# Help with php code - need to add condition to make one link https

Tags: php, html, wordpress, https

I have a wordpress blog and I need to make one of the pages secure.  I have been told to make the link to that page point to https://claimpage.html as opposed to http://claimpage.html.

The problem is I don't actually create the menu that links the user to the individual pages.  This is done automatically by the code in the background.  I think I need to put in some sort of an IF statement, saying, if the title of the page is "claim now" then use https otherwise use http.

I found this code in the header.php so I think my changes need to go in here but I'm not really sure what to do.

```
<div id="navbar">
  <ul class="menu">
   <li class="<?php if ( is_home() ) { ?>current_page_item<?php } else { ?>page_item<?php } ?>"><a href="<?php echo get_settings('home'); ?>"><?php _e('Home'); ?></a></li>
   <?php wp_list_pages('sort_column=id&depth=1&title_li='); ?>
   <?php wp_register('<li>','</li>'); ?>
  </ul>
</div> <!-- end of #navbar -->
```

Any suggestions as to how I can make one page that I know the title and url or https while the others are kept using normal http?

The site is hosted on a secure server so I do have an ssl certificate.

Answer (score 2):

Following on from prodigitalson's idea. You can add this to your .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule ^claimpage.html https://claimpage.html [R=301,L]
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: I'll try this, looks like the site has not fully changed over to the secure server, it still says install in progress. I'll add in this code once it is finished installing

Answer (score 0):

Use a Rewrite rule or RedirectMatch in your .htaccess. That will take care if redirecting the link without modifying the code.

Answer (score 0):

if you only have one language and your link to this site is static paste it statically into your theme.

```
<div id="navbar">
  <ul class="menu">
   <li class="<?php if ( is_home() ) { ?>current_page_item<?php } else { ?>page_item<?php } ?>"><a href="<?php echo get_settings('home'); ?>"><?php _e('Home'); ?></a></li>
   <?php wp_list_pages('sort_column=id&depth=1&title_li='); ?>
   <?php wp_register('<li>','</li>'); ?>
   <li><a href="https://yoursecurelink">my secure link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div> <!-- end of #navbar -->
```

there is no need for regex, IF or ELSE, or something. your link is statically i think, so just paste it in.